What happened to a Hebrew slave
When a Hebrew slave sold themselves into slavery did they have to sell everything they owned or anything else?

Well usually you would only sell yourself into slavery if you had absolutely nothing to your name

Why would they have to sell everything they owned?

If someone was sold by bais din to pay a debt, the creditor can take assets starting with the best land the debtor owns. Presumably they can take moveable property too and may prefer this over a slave if he doesn't actually need a slave. But someone could choose to sell himself to support his family and there would be nobody to compell him to sell his possessions . This is an excellent question

Does it matter whether he was sold by bais din or whether he sold himself? If he doesn't sell his possessions, does the master aquire them? What about the usufruct of the possessions?
